# Which side of this board is the capacitor polarity indicating?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, diagram

In this capacitor slot, which side is the negative and which is the positive? I've never seen this symbol before. I'm assuming the bottom is positive but want to make sure.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Top should be negative, the cup and thick bar historically mean that... I'm 99% sure.

Comment: I would have guessed that too, but then it looks like a non-polarized Layden jar.  https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/01049.png but then again allabout site is not IPC nor is Pinterest https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f4/b4/4c/f4b44c0247b95fefbfc401cf8278b865.jpg

Comment: Note the cap outline on the PCB is thicker on one side than the other... and that other caps have the thick part by a white stripe, which I assume is negative (but you can check by looking at that stripe on the cap).

Comment: Bottom is positive, just compare with the markings on the other polarized capacitors.

Comment: the top part of the symbol represents the metal can

Comment: Outer part is can. Can is negative (kept people safer in the +400V anode supply days. Which I suppose have come back, with offline switching supplies...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the other capacitors around it and how they're oriented. Notice the thicker part of the circle on the negative side. Even ignoring the symbol in the center of the footprint, you can tell which side is positive and which is negative based on the context of the other caps.

Positive is the short line in the symbol, negative is the upside-down "U" cup shape going around the positive terminal.